# multiple transforms in the single transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have some styles:

```
.btn-link{
     will-change: rotate, scale;
     transition: scale .2s ease-in-out, rotate .2s .15s ease-in-out;

    &:hover{
     color: darken(red, 10%);
     transform: scale(1.1,1.1) rotate(.5turn);
    }
}
```

and it's doesn't work. In the transition I can write more globaly - transform, but my animation include different transormations with different time of starts and delays. How you do it?

Comment: You cannot associate different times and delays for each item of the transform stack as far as I am aware. `transform` is a single property and all transforms that are part of the stack get the same duration and delay. If you want each item of the transform stack to have its own  delay then you may have to use JS and control it using timeouts.

Comment: Thank's, I understand that without js i can't do it.

Comment: Are you open to trying out new JS libraries that not only do what you are trying to do so very well, but do a bunch of other things. All that, with minimal file-size and a relatively easy to understand API. I am talking about **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)** by the way, heard of it?

Comment: This is not how `transition` works. The parameter needs to be a *css property* (eg `transform`), however you're applying it to specific *transforms*